# CalDAV command line client?

Tags: command-line, software-rec

I'd like to do my CalDAV from the CLI just as I do my IMAP from `mutt`, what is my best bet as far as clients are concerned?

Comment: Another option is wyrd/[remind](https://www.roaringpenguin.com/products/remind) + [remind-caldav](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/remind-caldav). The latter comes separate pull and push tools, which presumably don't do things like check for conflicts.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The CalDAV wiki has [a list of clients](https://wiki.davical.org/index.php?title=CalDAV_Clients), only one of which seems to be a command line tool: [cadaver](http://www.webdav.org/cadaver/).

More recently, a CalDav capable command line client called [khal](http://lostpackets.de/khal/) has appeared to fill this gap. I have been using it and integrating it with [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org/) and it is working nicely. With some [simple scripts](http://jasonwryan.com/blog/2014/04/05/calendar/), I can view calendar information in Mutt and then import it to `khal` where it is then synched to my CalDav server and propagated to my other machines or devices.

It is still described as in "the early stages of development", but I have found it to be stable and simple to use.

The next step, according to the developer, is to use [vdirsyncer](https://github.com/untitaker/vdirsyncer/) as the backend for synching: it is set up much like [OfflineIMAP](http://offlineimap.org/), with Remote and Local data stores: synching between the two. Currently there is a vdir branch to test this functionality.

Comment: N.B. that cadaver [appears](http://wiki.davical.org/index.php/CalDAV_Clients/Cadaver) to be a generic DAV client. Hence, you can manually interface with DAV to extract and submit CalDAV data. However, there is no specific CalDAV functionality built in.

Comment: The only thing out there that doesn't appear dead is khal - which looks quite nice.

Answer (score 9):

[Calcurse](http://calcurse.org/) does support CalDAV (still experimental) in the latest release. It's packaged for the most common GNU/Linux Distributions and BSDs.

Answer (score 1):

There is a library in the project [caldavserver](http://trac.calendarserver.org/wiki/CalDAVClientLibrary) that seems to be currently mantained (cadaver hasn't done a release since 2009)
With the stock client you could do some of the stuff you need.